# Why can't I open this workspace?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, python-addin

I used python add in to make a tool bar in Arcmap that edits features on a map. It works on a file geodatabase, but not on an ArcSDE version one. I've been getting an FDO error: 0. The solutions that I've found all involve opening a workspace, but I'm getting an error doing that as well. Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```py
        outFolderPath = r"U:\tempStuff"
        outName = "Stuff.sde"
        databasePlatform = "SQL_Server"
        instance = "SQL Server"
        arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(outFolderPath, outName,
                                                  databasePlatform,
                                                  instance)
        print "Centroid of buidling:(%r,%r) Side length: %r" % (xCoordinate,
                                                                yCoordinate,
                                                                bob)
        print "workspace is %r" % outName #outName is workspace

        #Start edit session with an undo/redo stack then start
        #edit operation
        print "Starting editing"
        edit = arcpy.da.Editor(outName) #outName is workspace Line 86
        edit.startEditing(True, True)
        edit.startOperation()

        #stuff happens

        cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor( fc, ["SHAPE@"])
        cursor.insertRow([stuff])
            #stop the edit operation and then save changes
        edit.stopOperation()
        edit.stopEditing(True)

        del cursor
        print "Building should be drawn"
```

This is the exact error I've been getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\153289\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{0BEF4E61-6332-4BCA-A908-959CA3C0B4E7}\leetScripts_addin.py", line 86, in onClick
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(outName)#outName is workspace
RuntimeError: cannot open workspace
```

What's am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Maybe `outName` needs to be a full path?

Comment: The instance value is wrong.  Use  'hostname' or 'hostname\nonDefaultService'.  You can also use `createdConn = arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(...` to obtain the full path

Comment: I can't tell you the hostname of your server.

Comment: @Vince ah. My mistake I didn't see that variable and thought you were talking about how I called stuff. Do you know how to find out what the host name of my server is using Arc?

Comment: You haven't supplied a username and password there anywhere, perhaps it's not a workspace because of *permission denied*. Try the full path as in the answer but also supply your credentials. Of course you may be supplying these but have removed them for secrecy - that's smart, but normally you'd mask the password like password ='XXXXXXXX' to show that you're supplying it but not actually revealing it.

Comment: Hostnames are tricky, even locally, since a single box can have multiple IP addresses, and a different name on each.  Python can often get you *a* name, but whether it's the *right* name isn't an easy call.  There's no way to tell what a remote server name might be.

Comment: @Vince I looked in the ArcGIS administrator I think I have a correct hostname, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson new error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\153289\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.3\AssemblyCache\{0BEF4E61-6332-4BCA-A908-959CA3C0B4E7}\leetScripts_addin.py", line 73, in onClick
    'OPERATING_SYSTEM_AUTH')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 16531, in CreateDatabaseConnection
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000565: Could not connect to server.
Failed to execute (CreateDatabaseConnection).`

Comment: If you are getting a new error I think it is best to research/ask about it as a new question rather than in a single one that will "strand" any answers to your original question.

Comment: I'm assuming you can create a connection with ArcCatalog, right? Is your server/instance specified correctly? Is your login role authorized in SDE and the database to allow connection? PolyGeo is correct, this is a new error that is sufficiently different to warrant a new question.. but try first in your python console to connect, if it works there but not in your script with the same parameters it's not just a typo and is a much more serious problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not referencing the full path to your newly created SDE connection. Try this:

```
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(os.path.join(outFolderPath, outName))
```

Comment: Just tried that. Same error message.

Comment: It's working for me now. No idea why lol

Answer (score 0):

I think `arcpy.da.Editor` requires an arcpy environment workspace (`arcpy.env.workspace`) to be set.

This is what I've got in one of my Editing python scripts

```
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(outFolderPath, outName)

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace) 
edit.startEditing(True, True)
edit.startOperation()
```

Comment: That returns the original error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error. The same script worked in one environment (10.4.1) but not failed in another (10.6.1). I simply added `import os`, and the script came back to life.