# "Runtime error: cannot open workspace" after creating a connection file and changing the version

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

I'm trying to run an update cursor. Usually if I have an issue with databases with enterprise connections, making a connection file clears it up. This time when I tried to execute my code I just get a `Runtime Error: cannot open workspace` message.

I went ahead and changed the version but that didn't work either. I also tried using the workspace without the connection file and I got the same error. I've yet to make it past `edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)`

Here's the bulk of my immaculate code:

```
def build_connection_file():
    """This function handles everything involved in building a connection
file to the feature class"""

    directory = r"C:\TempConnectionFiles"
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.path.makedirs(directory)

    feature_dataset = r"ThisIsReal"
    feature_class = r"ThisIsReal"

    sde = r"Database Connections\Real.sde"

    versions = [version.name for version in arcpy.da.ListVersions(sde)\
                if (getpass.getuser() in version.name)]

    print versions[-1]

    connection_name = "ThisIsReal.sde"
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, connection_name)):
        arcpy.CreateDatabaseConnection_management(
            out_folder_path = directory,
            out_name = connection_name,
            database_platform = "real_platform",
            instance = "real_instance",
            account_authentication = "OPERATING_SYSTEM_AUTH",
            username = "",
            password = "",
            save_user_pass = "DO_NOT_SAVE_USERNAME",
            database = "real_database",
            version_type = "TRANSACTIONAL",
            version = versions[-1])

    connection_feature_class_full = os.path.join(
        directory, connection_name, feature_dataset,
        feature_class)

    print connection_feature_class_full

    #this was required last time I did this.
    table_view = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(
        in_table = connection_feature_class_full,
        out_view = r"connection_table", where_clause = "",
        workspace ="", field_info = "")

    arcpy.ChangeVersion_management(
        in_features = table_view, version_type = "TRANSACTIONAL",
        version_name = versions[-1], date = '')

    print("changed version")

    return connection_feature_class_full

connection_feature_class = build_connection_file()
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(connection_feature_class_full)
edit.startEditing(True, False)
edit.startOperation()
```

Is there a setting in my database that could be responsible for this? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue is that I was using

`edit = arcpy.da.Editor(connection_feature_class_full)`

when I should have been using

`edit = arcpy.da.Editor(
    os.path.join(My connection file out_folder_path, My connection file out_name)`

I found this from [Why can't I open this workspace?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195129) Usually my code throws an error if I don't do it the first way way, but not today. This is really something esri should look into.